# Combining several files into a single CSV

Tags: shell-script, files

Input files:

File: `1.txt`:

```
1
2
3
```

File: `2.txt`:

```
Apple
Mango
Orange
```

File: `3.txt`:

```
55
100
30
```

Desired Output:

File: `example.csv`:

```
column1   column2   column3
1         Apple     55
2         Mango     100
3         Orange    30
```

Answer (score 14):

With `paste`:

```
paste 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

The output is:

```
1       Apple   55
2       Mango   100
3       Orange  30
```

Comment: Question specified CSV, which REQUIRES commas.  Answer is missing commas.

Comment: @Yedric This is nowhere mentioned, the example output shows clearly tabs...

Comment: the title says CSV.  I assumed that the output example was shown with separated columns for clarity.

Comment: @Yedric CSV may use any delimiter, escape character and quoting character. What makes it CSV is the consistent use of these characters and the way quoting of fields with embedded delimiters, newlines and quotes work.

Answer (score 8):

To create a csv file, you can do it like this (setting the delimiter to a comma) :

```
paste -d"," 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt >> example.csv
```

Comment: Along with the fact that it's nearly the same answer as mine, it pastes the ouput together with a comma, not with tabs.

Comment: Question specified CSV, which REQUIRES commas.

Comment: Hi dudes, Thanks for your replies. Is it possible to copy these txt files as required previously in the 3 rd sheet in csv file? Look forward for your valuable reply.